# Minimize Rosenbrock Function With Conjugate Gradient Method

Tags: optimization

I want to minimize

$$ f(x,y) = (1-x)^2 + 100(y-x^2)^2 $$

For the conjugate gradient method I need the quadratic form

$$  f(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}^{\text{T}}\mathbf{b} $$

Is this even possible to bring the Rosenbrock function in this form? If yes, how would I have to do this?

Comment: No, it is not possible. You need the *nonlinear* conjugate gradient method; see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_conjugate_gradient_method) or Ch. 14 of [Jonathan Shewchuk's introduction to CG](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake-papers/painless-conjugate-gradient.pdf).

Comment: Thank you, if you want to put this in an answer I can give you precious internet points :)